# Как сделать массив без использования квадратных скобок?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Как сделать массив без использования квадратных скобок?

Comment: Непонятно. Приведите примеры, опишите подробнее, что вы хотите.

Comment: А можно вопрос переформулировать? Массив - лишь удобный способ обращения к упорядоченным данным.

Comment: Макросом через #define

Comment: Использовать указатель

Answer (score 6):

Как и велосипед без колес... Вы поясните, что именно вы хотите?

Скобки использовать нельзя категорически? Вообще? тогда придется через `malloc`.

```
int a[10];
a[1] = 5;
```

меняем на

```
int*a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
*(a+1) = 5;
```

Так сойдет?

Comment: Можно триграфами ещё. `a??(10??)` :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    // конструктор использует агрегатный инициализатор
    std::array<int, 3> a1{ {1,2,3} };  // требуются двойные фигурные скобки,
    std::array<int, 3> a2 = {1, 2, 3}; // за исключением операций присваивания
    std::array<std::string, 2> a3 = { {std::string("a"), "b"} };

    // поддерживаются обобщённые алгоритмы
    std::sort(a1.begin(), a1.end());
    std::reverse_copy(a2.begin(), a2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    // поддерживается ranged for цикл
    for(auto& s: a3)
        std::cout << s << ' ';
}
```

[Из мануала](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)